# How to do group by and take Count of one column divide by count of unique of second column of data frame in python pandas?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, numpy

I have panda data frame with 4 column say 'col1', 'col2', 'col3' and 'col4' now I want to group by col1 and col2 and want to take aggregate say below.

```
Count(col3)/(Count(unique col4)) As result_col
```

How do I do this? I am using MySql with pandas.

I have tried many things from the internet but not getting an exact solution, that's why I am posting here. Give reason of downvote so I can improve my question.

Comment: Post raw data, code to create the df, your attempts and what the desired result should look like that is representative of your actual problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you need [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) by [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.size.html) and [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) and then [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) output columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1,1],
                   'col2':[4,4,6],
                   'col3':[7,7,9],
                   'col4':[3,3,5]})

print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     4     7     3
1     1     4     7     3
2     1     6     9     5

df1 = df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg({'col3':'size','col4':'nunique'})
df1['result_col'] = df1['col3'].div(df1['col4'])
print (df1)
           col4  col3  result_col
col1 col2                        
1    4        1     2         2.0
     6        1     1         1.0
```

Comment: Looks like it can help me...Let me try now...Thanks

Comment: Sure, please test it.

Comment: How can I get count based on specific condition say "Group by col1,col2 and get aggregate count(col3 where col3=7)" ? Can you please help me?

Comment: You need first [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) first - so `df1 = df[df.col3 == 7].groupby(['col1','col2']).agg({'col3':'size','col4':'nunique'})`

Comment: But I am not sure if understand, maybe better is create new question with sample and desired output.

Comment: Okay I will try and if I don't get output i will create new question

Comment: Sure, the best is test it in small sample and then apply solution to big real data.

Comment: Can i edit this question because I want to do this with the same group by query  you given in answer?

Comment: I think better is create new one with link to old question, because it is similar, but not same problem.

Comment: please check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42061323/how-to-do-group-by-and-take-count-of-unique-and-count-of-some-value-as-aggregate)