# How to do group by and take count of unique and count of some value as aggregate on same column in python pandas?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, numpy

My question is related to my previous [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022767/how-to-do-group-by-and-take-count-of-one-column-divide-by-count-of-unique-of-sec) but it's different. So I am asking the new question.

In above question see the answer of @jezrael.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1,1],
                   'col2':[4,4,6],
                   'col3':[7,7,9],
                   'col4':[3,3,5]})

print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     4     7     3
1     1     4     7     3
2     1     6     9     5

df1 = df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg({'col3':'size','col4':'nunique'})
df1['result_col'] = df1['col3'].div(df1['col4'])
print (df1)
           col4  col3  result_col
col1 col2                        
1    4        1     2         2.0
     6        1     1         1.0
```

Now here I want to take count for the specific value of `col4` . Say I also want to take count of `col4 == 3` in the same query.

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg({'col3':'size','col4':'nunique'}) ... + count(col4=='3')
```

How to do this in same above query I have tried bellow but not getting solution.

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg({'col3':'size','col4':'nunique','col4':'x: lambda x[x == 7].count()'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do some preprocessing by including the `col4==3` as a column ahead of time.  Then use `aggregate`

```
df.assign(result_col=df.col4.eq(3).astype(int)).groupby(
    ['col1', 'col2']
).agg(dict(col3='size', col4='nunique', result_col='sum'))

           col3  result_col  col4
col1 col2                        
1    4        2           2     1
     6        1           0     1
```

---

***old answers***

```
g = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])
g.agg({'col3':'size','col4': 'nunique'}).assign(
    result_col=g.col4.apply(lambda x: x.eq(3).sum()))

           col3  col4  result_col
col1 col2                        
1    4        2     1           2
     6        1     1           0
```

---

slightly rearranged

```
g = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])
final_df = g.agg({'col3':'size','col4': 'nunique'})
final_df.insert(1, 'result_col', g.col4.apply(lambda x: x.eq(3).sum()))
final_df

           col3  result_col  col4
col1 col2                        
1    4        2           2     1
     6        1           0     1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) with list of function in `dict` for column `col4`.

If need count `3` values the simpliest is `sum` `True` values in `x == 3`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])
        .agg({'col3':'size','col4': ['nunique', lambda x: (x == 3).sum()]})
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'<lambda>':'count_3'})
df1.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(x[0], x[1]) for x in df1.columns]
print (df1)
           col4_nunique  col4_count_3  col3_size
col1 col2                                       
1    4                1             2          2
     6                1             0          1
```

Comment: Let me check. And how can I give different column name for both results?

Comment: Is there anything on internet that i can take this small data and execute pandas on it?

Comment: I think there is no such free services.

Comment: This answer is also correct but I used @piRSquared's .assign() method before group by so I accepted his answer. Thanks..